# How can I do a find-replace for a Backslash (\) character in zshell?

Tags: string, zsh, find-replace

I'm trying to use a ZShell function to replace forward- and backslashes with a hyphen. So that "Hello/Every\Person" becomes "Hello-Every-Person". I can do it for the forward slash using

```
arg=${arg:gs/\//-}
```

but when I try the same syntax for the backslash it fails. Running

```
arg=${arg:gs/\//-}
arg=${arg:gs/\\/-}
```

produces "Hello-EveryPerson". It strips out the backslash, but doesn't do the replacement. I was expecting the normal rules of escaping characters to apply, so the double backslash would resolve to a character.

Can anyone tell me what I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

Works in `zsh` version 5.8 exactly as you expected.